# Dropdown Menu Items "Re-Close" Without Hover

Tags: jquery, menu-item, bootstrap

On the Joomla 3.3.1 site I have running at [Robosane.net](https://robosane.net), the only dropdown menu that I have is experiencing a very odd problem, it's hard to explain.

When the menu is clicked, it does not pop up until the mouse leaves the hover area, then re-enters. The menu also does not close when it's parent is clicked.

The site is using both JQuery and Bootstrap Javascript Frameworks.

This is a custom template I made, here's how the frameworks are listed:

```
// Add Stylesheets
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/bootstrap.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/landing-page.css');

// Add current user information
$user = JFactory::getUser();

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
//$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/jquery.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/template.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/bootstrap.js');
```

You can see how I intended for this to look by visiting [robobenklein.github.io/robosan3](http://robobenklein.github.io/robosan3), which is only a static mockup of the page.

Edit: When Javascript is merged, the problem no longer occurs, however the mobile menu collapse no longer closes once opened, and JS animations no longer function.

Comment: You are loading bootstrap twice. That could be the issue

Comment: Check your console log too. You have some Javascript errors which won't help